# ggplot in function using variables -- geom_density: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function to print and save some charts using ggplot2. When I executed to geom_density, the error message showed up.

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = 1:5, y = c(44.43, 72.36, 177.17, 515.09, 1403.33 : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 0
```

After some research, I found that I maybe miss the group name and some instruction. But, I cannot pinpoint this error. I have listed entire data.

```
library(ggplot2)
dt <- read.table("/R/10G.csv", header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
dt$Thread <- factor(dt$Thread)  # factorize 'Thread'
library(plyr)
dd.mean <- ddply(dt, 'Thread', summarize, TPS = round(mean(TPS), 2), RT = round(mean(RT), 2))
m <- ggplot(dd.mean, aes(x=Thread,y=RT, group=seq)) 
m + geom_density(fill=NA)
m + geom_text(data=dd.mean, aes(x=Thread, label=TPS), vjust=-2)
```

Comment: We don't have the file "/R/10G.csv" on our computers so we can't reproduce this example. Try using `dput(dt)` to print the table for us to import

Comment: Thanks. I will try to it. And I had uploaded the 10G.csv file on My Google Drive. You can download it from [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2yfJOAXDqTUVi1XZ1VnVUxZT0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: When using ggplot() you are trying to `group` by `seq` and I don't see `seq` anywhere in your data. When I remove `group=seq` I get a plot. I don't know if that was what you were after, but it works.

Comment: I want to draw the line chart, not the point chart only. I can draw the point chart. but I don't know how to connect all of point to line.In some search result, they suggested me that I needed to group its.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should research more into `ggplot()`, specifically `geom_line` and `geom_point`. I don't think `geom_density` is what you were looking for here. Below is an example of one way you could approach this task, but there are literally thousands of different approaches you could take, that's why I recommend looking into the documentation more, some links that may help:

- http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/.
- http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/geom_text

Note: I didn't factorize `dt$Thread`

```
library(plyr)

dd.mean <- ddply(dt, 'Thread', summarize, TPS = round(mean(TPS), 2), RT = round(mean(RT), 2))

ggplot(dd.mean, aes(x = Thread, y = RT)) + 
        geom_line(size = 1, alpha = 0.3, colour = "red") + 
        geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 1, colour = "red") +  
        geom_text(x = dd.mean$Thread, label = dd.mean$TPS, vjust = -2)
```